# How to append vector to list of vectors in R without resorting to indices?

Tags: r, list, append

Consider for example the list

```
lExample <- list(c(0, 1, 0), c(1, 3), c(4, 1, 6))
```

and two new vectors that we would like to append to the former list

```
v1 = c(5, 3)
v2 = rep(4, 5)
```

.
One way of doing so would be

```
lExample[[4]] <- v1
lExample[[5]] <- v2
```

but this would require keeping track of `length(lExample)` for each new vector we want to add.
Is there a way to append the new vectors similarly to using `c()` but without altering the structure of the appended vector? (`c(lExample, v1)` adds each element of `v1` as individual element of the list)

Answer (score 3):

What about using `c` like below?

```
> c(lExample, list(v1, v2))
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 0

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 1 6

[[4]]
[1] 5 3

[[5]]
[1] 4 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R approach

```
> unlist(list(lExample, list(v1, v2)), recursive=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 0

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 1 6

[[4]]
[1] 5 3

[[5]]
[1] 4 4 4 4 4
```